# adding PSQL to the .bash_profile mac

Tags: bash, postgresql, macos, shell

I installed a postgresql client to manage online database but the command, but the psql command was not known in the command line. So I tried to add it to my .bash_profile file but there went something wrong and now none of my commands can be found. Does somebody know how to fix it ?

this it the content of the file[enter image description here][1]

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=/Library/PostSQL/9.5/bin:psql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting `$PATH` instead of appending to it. Change the line to include the old `$PATH` too:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostSQL/9.5/bin
```